# applying class in ng-repeat if contained in another array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, ng-class

I am querying for a collection of IDs from Parse.com and showing them in my $scope as an array.

I would like to apply a class to the items in my $scope that match any one of these IDs, placing a border around the object illustrating that it is already contained in the 'saved' array. I have tried the following however not having any luck.

```
ng-class="{'approved': ParseSavedExercises.indexOf(exercise.id) == -1}"
```

in this case my `ParseSavedExercises`is my array to check against and exercise.id is what I am checking for.

here is a quick [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/884mj4b7/1/)

Comment: is `ParsedSavedExercises` exposed on the scope? Also, you'd probably want to store it in a hash, so that the lookup time complexity is O(1), rather than O(n) with `.indexOf`

Comment: I don't see any issue with that code specifically. We'll need to have more of your code. Maybe a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see here http://jsfiddle.net/e9pr4yqj/

Yours ParseSavedExercises contains string and id is number so no id existed in ParseSavedExercises

```
 $scope.ParseSavedExercises = ['2','3'];
```

change to

```
 $scope.ParseSavedExercises = [2,3];
```

or use

```
ng-class="{'approved': ParseSavedExercises.indexOf(exercise.id.toString()) == -1}"
```

like here http://jsfiddle.net/1ujgvL80/

Comment: ok they are returning from Parse as a string - I may have re-structure things or run `parseInt` many thanks

Comment: One final thing if you would be so kind... this is applying the class to items NOT contained, how can I change to `contained`

Comment: @Taylorsuk 'approved': ParseSavedExercises.indexOf(exercise.id.toString()) > -1